# multiple HTML tag update with ajax, jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, shell

Having a basic understanding about AJAX ,JQUERY here is my code for updating an html tag and showing "date" shell command result on it every seconds.

I am wondering how it is possible to expend this code and add some more tags and update them all. e.g i need to show cpu load, uptime,.....

test2.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(timestamp, 1000);
        });
        function timestamp() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/test2.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#timestamp').html(data);
                },
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="timestamp">clock</div>
<div id="uptime">to be done!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

test2.php:

```
<?php
    echo $timestamp=shell_exec('date');
    //echo $uptime=shell_exec('uptime -p');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about sending back JSON to your caller:

```
<?php

$data = [
     'timestamp' => shell_exec('date'),
     'uptime' => shell_exec('uptime -p')
     ];

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

And then this (or something similar) in your Javascript ...

```
success: function(data) {
     $('#timestamp').html(data.timestamp);
     $('#uptime').html(data.uptime);
},
```

Comment: thanks alot $('#timestamp').html(data.timestamp); not working by the way i used     success: function(data) {
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
document.getElementById("timestamp").innerHTML=obj.timestamp;